# HTML5 e-mail input doesn't validate utf-8 in Chrome 39

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome, utf-8

I have this element in my form:

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail">
```

When I enter `שלום@שלום.com`, Google Chrome 39 says:

[image: why?]

But why? I thought new e-mail addresses can have UTF-8 characters so that shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in Chrome or HTML specification. Check out these:

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=431550
- https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=15489

Here is a workaround: use `שלום@xn--9dbne9b.com` instead of `שלום@שלום.com`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `accept-charset="UTF-8"` to the `form` tag.?

---

Ideally, you set UTF-8 in the Content-Type http header: http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset

Or as a meta tag in your html:
`<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: Yes I did both but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This is to avoid SQL Injection.

```py
cur.execute("select UNAME from users where EMAIL=? and UPASS=?",(email,pwd))
```

[image]